# Computing a quadratic response using numpy linear algebra

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I am having trouble manipulating matrices in numpy. I have a vector of N inputs, theta, and I want to compute a scalar response using a quadratic model, theta^T A theta + theta^T b + c, where ^T denotes transpose, A is an NxN square matrix, b is an N-dimensional vector, and c is a scalar. When theta is an (NxM) matrix, meaning I have M theta values to propagate, I must compute theta^T A theta to yield an M dimensional matrix. In index notation, the computation is theta_{mj} A_{ji} theta_{im}, where m is not to be summed over.

If I just have one set of theta values, numpy's linear algebra works as expected (here, N=10 and M=1):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np                                            

In [2]: theta = np.ones(10)                                           

In [3]: A = np.ones((10, 10))                                         

In [4]: b = np.ones(10)                                               

In [5]: theta.T.dot(A).dot(theta) + theta.T.dot(b) + 1                
Out[5]: 111.0
```

I think the operation theta^T A theta may be different than a dot product here. I don't understand what is fundamentally different when I make theta an NxM matrix. I thought the extra dimension would naturally carry through this code, like it does with the b and c terms.

**How can I make numpy return an M-dimensional array from the operation theta^T A theta?**

I can only make it return square matrices. The dot product function unfortunately treats this operation as a matrix multiplication (here, N=10 and M=5):

```
In [6]: theta = np.ones((10, 5))
#       theta.T.dot(A).dot(theta) is equivalient to:
#             
#                 (M x N)           (N x N)  (N x M)
In [7]: np.matmul(theta.T, np.matmul(A,     theta))                      
Out[7]: 
array([[100., 100., 100., 100., 100.],
       [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.],
       [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.],
       [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.],
       [100., 100., 100., 100., 100.]])
```

In contrast, the b and c terms naturally carry the extra theta terms and provide the M-dimensional output I want:

```
In [8]: theta.T.dot(b) + 1                                           
Out[8]: array([11., 11., 11., 11., 11.])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

```
N,M = 10,5
A = np.random.randint(0,10,(N,N))
theta = np.random.randint(0,10,(N,M))
b = np.random.randint(0,10,N)
```

1) use the fact that >2D operands are treated as stacks by matmul:

```
(theta.T[:,None]@A@theta.T[...,None])[...,0,0] + b@theta + 1
# array([ 8188, 14837,  7697,  9719,  7262])
```

or

2) use `einsum`

```
np.einsum("ik,ij,jk->k",theta,A,theta) + b@theta + 1
# array([ 8188, 14837,  7697,  9719,  7262])
```

Compare to one-by-one evaluation for validation:

```
[t@A@t + b@t + 1 for t in theta.T]
# [8188, 14837, 7697, 9719, 7262]
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the name of the notation that uses the `@` symbols here? I have not seen that before.

Comment: It's the matrix multiplication operator. The corresponding dunder is `.__matmul__`.